# 「Text」の折り返し設定が保持されない

Tags: emeditor

テキストファイルの折り返し設定を「設定の定義」→「Text」→「プロパティ」の「基本」タブで変更すると、その時は折り返しの設定が反映されますが、Emeditorを立ち上げ直すと既定（折り返さない）に戻ってしまいます。
同時に変更した「Text」の他の項目については再起動後も保持されます。
また、「Text」ではなくユーザー定義の設定では再起動後も折り返し設定が保持されます。
「Text」の折り返し設定が保持されないのは仕様なのでしょうか。

- EmEditor Professional (64-bit)
  Version 20.1.1
- Windows 10 Pro for Workstations Version 2004 (OS build 19041.508)

Answer (score 0):

[ツール] メニューの [カスタマイズ] を選択した時に表示される [カスタマイズ] ダイアログの [表示] ページで、[折り返しモードを同期する] オプションが設定されているでしょうか?

また、巨大ファイルを開く時、CSV モードに変更する時などは、折り返さないに変更されるようになっています。

Comment: [折り返しモードを同期する] オプションは有効になっています。開いているテキストファイルは5000文字未満です。

Comment: もしかして、[カスタマイズ] ダイアログの [同期] ページで [設定を同期する] が設定されているのでしょうか?

Comment: [設定を同期する] は設定されていません。

Comment: こちらでは問題が再現できなため、大変お手数ですが、次のような手順を行っていただけると幸いです。

1. [ツール] メニューの [インポートとエクスポート] を選択し、[すべての設定をレジストリ ファイルにエクスポート] を選択してください (ただし、ポータブル版の場合は、[すべての設定を INI ファイルにエクスポート] を選択してください)。

2. [ツール] メニューの [すべてのコマンド] - [ツール] - [すべての設定をリセット] を選択します。もし、これで設定がリセットされない場合には、一度、EmEditor をアンインストールし、アンインストールの最中、設定を保存するかどうかの質問には「いいえ」を選択します。そして、再度インストールします。

3. これで問題が解決した場合には、エクスポートしたファイルのすべて (AppData を含む) を zip に圧縮して、私宛 (tech @ emurasoft.com) に送っていただければ幸いです。

4. [ツール] メニューの [インポートとエクスポート] を選択し、エクスポートしたファイルをインポートしていただければ、元の設定に戻ります。

Comment: 返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません。設定のリセットでText形式の折り返し設定が保持されるようになりました。また、何故か問題が発生していた時の設定ファイルをインポートしても折り返し設定がリセットされなくなりました。